# sql запрос Удаление клиента если он ничего не купил

Tags: sql

У меня есть две таблицы - Клиент и Покупка. Они связаны по коду Клиент.КодКлиета = Покупка.Клиент. Так вот, как мне удалить клиента который ничего не купил? Поясняю - если клиент купил товар, его id отобразиться в таблице Покупка. А если не купил, значит его id та мне будет. Так, вот как это реализовать? что необходимо дописать?:

Delete from Клиент
where КодКлиета = (select Клиент from Покупка П, Клиент К where КодКлиента = Клиент and Клиент = КодКлиента)

Comment: При наличии FK проверять ничего не нужно - просто безусловно удаляй клиента, и всё. Если у него есть покупки, сервер не позволит удалить запись, на которую есть ссылки в таблице покупок.

Comment: Можно уточнить? что дописать к удалению Delete from Клиент where КодКлиета = ??? Иначе если я напишу просто Delete from Клиент - удалиться все. P.S(Sql Запрос выполняется в Delphi)

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Либо ты работаешь с одним клиентом, и тогда ты знаешь его код. Либо ты не знаешь код клиента вообще - ну... можно попробовать поиск на потолке или высасывание из пальца. Однако ДОБАВИТЬ ранее ты его как-то умудрился?

Comment: Клиентская база описана. Много клиенто. Нужно вычислить клиентов которые ничего не купили - и удалить. Ясно одно - что если клиент ничего не купил - его id Не будет светиться в таблице Покупка.

Comment: Ну так просто удаляй всех с игнорированием ошибки внешнего ключа - удалятся только те, которые такого ограничения не имеют. Ну или стандартно - WHERE NOT EXISTS с коррелированным подзапросом.

Comment: У вас таблицы НА РУССКОМ?! Это извращение ‍♀️

Comment: Пасиба. Буду делать. А то что таблички на русском - это неважно))

Comment: Может быть, клиент что-то купит в будущем, зачем же сразу удалять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM Clients c
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM Purchases p
                   WHERE c.id = p.client_id )
```

Comment: ГОТОВ ПОЦЕЛОВАТЬ ВАС!

Comment: @streatbeat если ответ решил вашу задачу, отметьте его зеленой галочкой как верный.